# What's the difference between the "read" and "view" privileges in Nexus?

Tags: nexus

I've been wondering what the exact difference between the "view" and "read" privileges in Sonatype Nexus is. Could somebody please clarify?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "read" privilege allows artifacts to be downloaded.  The "view" privilege allows a user to see artifacts in the UI (assuming they also have the needed "read" privilege").